# Add .found = true values to a delineated string Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am searching through a word document for values using the find function. When the values are found I am attempting to place them in delineated string that will be used later in the script.

I am able to find these values, but when I do the script adds **all** the values in my search parameters to the string. I need it to only add the values that are actually in the document.

```
Sub FilePick()


Dim propstr As String
 Dim wordcollection(10) As String
    Dim words As Variant
wordcollection(0) = "PJ"
wordcollection(1) = "E1233"
wordcollection(2) = "E048"
wordcollection(3) = "E144"
wordcollection(4) = "E849"
wordcollection(5) = "E977"
wordcollection(6) = "IL0021"
wordcollection(7) = "MISC001"
wordcollection(8) = "CG0001"
wordcollection(9) = "CG2107"
wordcollection(10) = "Blah"
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
For Each words In wordcollection
With Selection.Find
.Text = words

 .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Format = True
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .MatchWildcards = False
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False

If .Found = True Then
propstr = propstr & " " & words
             End If
            Selection.Find.Execute
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LBound` and `UBound` to iterate through all the elements of the `wordcollection` Array; also, move your `.Execute` within the `With...End With` block and then check `If .Found`.

```
Sub FilePick()
    Dim propstr As String
    Dim wordcollection(10) As String
    Dim i As Integer

    wordcollection(0) = "PJ"
    wordcollection(1) = "E1233"
    wordcollection(2) = "E048"
    wordcollection(3) = "E144"
    wordcollection(4) = "E849"
    wordcollection(5) = "E977"
    wordcollection(6) = "IL0021"
    wordcollection(7) = "MISC001"
    wordcollection(8) = "CG0001"
    wordcollection(9) = "CG2107"
    wordcollection(10) = "Blah"

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    For i = LBound(wordcollection) To UBound(wordcollection)
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = wordcollection(i)
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = True
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            .Execute

            If .Found Then
                propstr = propstr & " " & wordcollection(i)
            End If
        End With
    Next i

    Debug.Print "Result: " & propstr
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! That got me a bit further on this project.